# No Internet except over ethernet; WIFI connects but internet unavailable

Tags: pi-3, wifi, raspbian-jessie

I have 5 Raspberry Pi 3's around my house doing various things.

Last night I purchased and configured a new one - but I can't access the Internet via WIFI.

If I plug in an ethernet cable, the Internet works perfectly. I can connect to my WIFI network without problems, I can even SSH into this new PI when connected to my network.

But I can't access the Internet.

I have already configured my SSID like this:

*In /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf*

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=US

network={
        ssid="my_network"
        psk="my_password"
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK    
}
```

I assume this has something to do with the default gateway, but I know very little about default gateways. Here's the output of "route -n":

```
/home/pi> route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
```

To recap:

- Internet works when I plug in ethernet
- I can connect to my local WIFI network
- When connected to my local WIFI I can ssh into pi
- When connected to my local network, I am unable to access the Internet
- Running the most up-to-date Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)

What else can I try?

Comment: post the output of `ifconfig`

Answer (score 2):

Connect to your local net and ping google.com from the command line.  If you get something about not finding the host, try `ping -c 3 8.8.8.8`  If the numeric ping works and not the ping to google, the name resolution is messed up.  That's what I've messed up most often.  `/etc/resolv.conf` should contain
the address of a nameserver -- if nothing else, the line `nameserver 8.8.8.8` should work.